Pivot dataframe into two seperate tables
I have found a similar question, but I haven't found a solution that works for my case.
I have a dataframe looks like this:
ID   Counterparty   Date         Commodity   Deal    Price   Total
--   ------------   -----        --------    -----   -----  ------
1     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    10.00   100.00
2     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    10.00   100.00
3     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    10.00   100.00
4     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    10.00   100.00
5     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    10.00   100.00
6     party1        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    10.00   100.00
7     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    5.00   50.00
8     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    5.00   50.00
9     party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Sell    5.00   50.00
10    party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    5.00   50.00
11    party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    5.00   50.00
12    party2        04/03/2024     Oil       Buy    5.00   50.00

my objective is to group data by Commodity and Deal so that I get a dataframe like this:
Counterparty      Commodity     Deal      Total
party1             Oil          Sell      300
party1             Oil          Buy       300
party2             Oil          Sell      150
party2             Oil          Buy       150

Up to this point, I have it working with this code:
df_grouped = df.groupby(['Counterparty', 'Commodity', 'Deal'])['Total'].sum().reset_index()

The second groupby turns it into this:
out = [x for _, x in df_grouped.groupby('DealType')]

Counterparty      Commodity     Deal      Total
party1             Oil          Buy       300
party2             Oil          Buy       150

Counterparty      Commodity     Deal      Total
party1             Oil          Sell      300
party2             Oil          Sell      150


I need to pivot the table into 3 seperate dataframes. One df for Sells, One df for buys and one df for total. It should look like this:
Sell
          Oil    ... ... ... 
party 1   300.00 ... ... ... 
party 2   150.00 ... ... ...

Buy
          Oil    ... ... ... 
party 1   300.00 ... ... ... 
party 2   150.00 ... ... ...

Total 
          Oil    ... ... ... 
party 1   600.00 ... ... ... 
party 2   300.00 ... ... ...


I am trying to use this, but it is throwing a duplicate index error which makes sense, but am unsure how to go about solving the issue:
df_pivot = df_grouped.pivot(index='Counterparty', columns='Commodity', values='MTMValue').fillna(0).rename_axis(None, axis=0)

Is pivot the correct approach to this solution? or is there a better way to achieve my results?

Don't pivot, use again groupby: out = dict(list(df_grouped.groupby('Deal'))). Then out['Sell']/out['Buy']/…

wouldn't I have to pivot after the second groupby though?

If your goal is to split the DataFrame in 3, no, you don't need to pivot.

The second groupby was what I was missing you were right, but the final result did need a pivot. I updated the intermediate step with data to show what I mean
